# cut -d – Delimiter is still shown in the output. How to remove it simply?

Tags: cut

Why the delimiter is still shown in the output? I thought field 2 and 4 would be shown without the `-` delimiter. How to use `cut` command to not show at the same time the delimiter itself used to separate fields?

```bash
$ curl -s -m 2 https://am.i.mullvad.net/json | jq '.mullvad_exit_ip_hostname'
"nl-ams-wg-002"

$ curl -s -m 2 https://am.i.mullvad.net/json | jq '.mullvad_exit_ip_hostname' | sd '\"' '' | cut -d '-' -f 2,4
ams-002
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `sd` (whatever that is) or `cut` here:

```
curl -s -m 2 https://am.i.mullvad.net/json |
  jq -r '.mullvad_exit_ip_hostname|split("-")|.[1]+.[3]'
```

As to the general question about removing the delimiter, with the GNU implementation of `cut`, you can use the `--output-delimiter` option with an empty delimiter:

```
$ echo a-b-c-d-e | cut -d- -f 2,4
b-d
$ echo a-b-c-d-e | cut -d- --output-delimiter= -f 2,4
bd
```

Beware of the surprising behaviour of `cut` when the input has no delimiter:

```
$ echo abc | cut -d- -f 2,4
abc
```

Adding the `-s` option removes the non-delimited lines, that is those that have 0 or 1 fields, not the ones that don't have the requested fields.

You can use `awk` instead of `cut` to get more flexibility (and avoid the GNUism):

```
$ echo a-b-c-d | awk -F- '{print $2 $4}'
bd
```

Or

```
$ echo a-b-c-d | awk -F-  'NF >= 4 {print $2 $4}'
bd
```

To only print something for the lines¹ that contain at least 4 fields.

---

<sup>¹ yes, `awk` (by default), like `cut` process each line one at a time, while `jq`'s `split` will process the string as a whole even if it contains newline characters.</sup>

Comment: FYI: [sd](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/linux-sd-command/) ... some sort of `sed` surrogate.